# Validating Reactive Form after setting values manually in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am setting manually a reactive Form when some events happen.
They are updated, although they don't pass any kind of validation.

It would be something like

```
this.FORM.controls.WHATEVERINPUT.setValue(X);
```

The point is that I am using Material Design and Angular 5 so in the template I have this structure

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput formControlName="WHATEVERINPUT">
<mat-error *ngIf="FORM?.controls.WHATEVERINPUT.errors">
 ... is required & Minimum of 5 characters
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

which works completely fine, except with those values I mentioned before.

I  have already played a little bit in the controller with

```
  this.FORM.controls.WHATEVERINPUT.markAsTouched();
    this.FORM.controls.WHATEVERINPUT.markAsDirty();
    this.FORM.updateValueAndValidity();
```

in several ways but I haven't already got a the value **validated**

I appreciate if someone can help me in any way
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your typescript code for your component? How do you create your controller, and what kind of `Validators` are you using?

Comment: Here is a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loj2zl?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Simple answer**

You can call `this.form.get('username').markAsTouched();` after you set the value.

**Another answer**

If you put your buttons inside the form, add an `(ngSubmit)="USR($event)"` as an attribute to your form tag, and add `type="submit"` on your button you will make Angular detect if the form is valid or not, and then the error message will be displayed.

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)=USR($event)>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button type="button" color="primary" [style.margin]="'12px'" (click)="PWD()">Update password with value</button>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [style.margin]="'12px'">Update username required error</button>
</form>
```

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-button-submit)